# Expected momentum ground state electron in $\rm H$ atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, wavefunction

I want to calculate $\langle p_x\rangle$ and $\langle p_x^2\rangle$ for ground state electron in $\rm H$ atom.

Radial function
$$
\psi(r)=Ae^{-r/a}
$$
Momentum operator in 3D:
$$
\hat{\vec p}=\frac{\hbar}{i}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)=\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla
$$
Momentum operator 1D:
\begin{align}
\hat{p}_{x} & =\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx}
\\
\langle p_x\rangle & =\int_V \psi^*(r)*\hat{p}_{x}*\psi(r) dV
\end{align}
Intuitively, $\langle p_x\rangle=0$ but how do I calculate it? Should I change the operator for one expressed in spherical coordinates or something else?
And for $\langle p_x^2\rangle$ I would just square the momentum operator and use it instead.

Comment: The integral is really not that hard to calculate in Cartesian coordinates, what exactly is the difficulty you're facing?

Comment: The difficulty I have is that my operator is in xyz coordinates but my function is radial- dependent on (r). So how can I calculate it. Or can I just simply use r=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) substitute it in radial function construct the integral and calculate it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the uncertainty principle to estimate the ground state energy of hydrogen](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183960/)

Comment: Use the chain rule to take the derivative of psi(r(x)), that is easier than substituting $r$. You'll need the chain rule for functions of more than one variable.

Comment: Ouch my bad about the ∇ of course it is not. But could you @EmilioPisanty please help my with the problem? I am still lost in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a spherically-symmetric state:

- $⟨p_x⟩=0$ by parity symmetry. This can be proved rigorously, by changing variables $\vec r \mapsto -\vec r$ and showing the expectation value must both change sign and remain unchanged.
- All three squared components, $⟨p_x^2⟩$, $⟨p_y^2⟩$ and $⟨p_z^2⟩$, must be equal, so therefore $⟨p_x^2⟩=\frac13⟨p^2⟩$. The latter can be evaluated directly using the spherical-coordinates expression for the laplacian.

The rest of the work is for you to do.